# Is there a way to Invert jQuery UI icons or Bootstrap icons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

Very simple question.
I'd like to be able to invert the icon vertically.
Either using jQuery UI or Bootstrap icons.

http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/icons/

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons

For example, the icon for "refresh" would be very handy as a "rotate" either clockwise or counterclockwise for image viewing. Is there a way to do this without having to get new icons?

Clarification: I do NOT want to rotate the image. I want to take a non-symetrical icon and ***invert it so I get a mirror image of it.***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply css class on those icon which you want to rotate
I have created a fiddle , you can check here

https://jsbin.com/rekuse/edit?html,css,js,output

```
.rotate-90 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
```

And if you want to flip the icon so this

```
.flip {
   -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
   -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
   -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
   transform: scaleX(-1);
   filter: FlipH;
}
```

Comment: This just rotates the image right? If I have an icon that's an arrow going in the clockwise direction and you rotate it, it's still pointing clockwise. The goal would be to make a clockwise icon change into counterclockwise.

Comment: Bam, that's it! Thank you! I edited your fiddle so it shows the difference between the flipped and regular icon. https://jsbin.com/lobaciwoye/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: greate... stay happy.. stay blessed :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a repeatable rotate, you can do:

```js
$(".rotate-left").click(function(){
  var $img = $(".Image");
  var rotation = ($img.prop("angle")||0)+90;
  $img.prop("angle", rotation%360);
  $img.css("transform","rotate("+$img.prop("angle")+"deg)")
})
```

And Likewise for Rotate Right:

```js
$(".rotate-right").click(function(){
  var $img = $(".Image");
  var rotation = ($img.prop("angle")||0)-90;
  $img.prop("angle", rotation%360);
  $img.css("transform","rotate("+$img.prop("angle")+"deg)")
})
```

Comment: This just rotates the the image. This won't work in the case where the image is not symmetrical.

Answer (score 0):

To do the icon rotate, you can simply attach the .rotated class to the icon.

```css
.rotated {transform: rotateY(180deg);}
```

EDIT: @matrixugly It does, rotateY mirrors the div, essentially giving you a counterlockwise icon from its counterpart, and vise versa

Comment: See the question. I do not want to rotate, but to flip.

Comment: Yes this rotates on the Y axis which gives you a mirror image as you said in your post. http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/L17950wk/

Comment: It's a good idea, but this does not work if the icon is asymmetrical. For example an arrow pointing counterclockwise rotated 180 degrees will still be pointing in the counterclockwise direction. Your idea does work under the assumption that the icon is symmetrical. :)

Comment: No, it does work for asymmetrical icons. Here's the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/jpL2ebzf/2/